# Width using percentages not working with inner divs

Tags: html, css

I have two divs. One is the container div and the other ones are 3 inner divs.
Outer div is using flexbox
Setting width of 3 inner divs to 20% doesn't do anything

HTML

```css
.links{
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    height: 2%;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 45%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.link_line{
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
 <div class='links'>
    <a href=""><div class='link_line'>LInk1</div></a>
    <a href=""><div class='link_line'>LInk2</div></a>
    <a href=""><div class='link_line'>LInk3</div></a>  
 </div>
```

NOTE: Links div is inside yet another div

Comment: because 20% of 0 is 0 ... 20% need to be applied to `a` not div

Comment: Yepp, you need to apply a width and height on parent, if you set a % width on the child. If you would set `px`, `vw`, `vh`, `em`, `rem` unit it would work without parent size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must apply a minimum width and height for the parent element.

```css
a{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
.links{
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    height: 2%;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 45%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.link_line{
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
 <div class='links'>
  <a href=""><div class='link_line'></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class='link_line'></div></a>
  <a href=""><div class='link_line'></div></a>  
 </div>
```